# Get rate in Excel without using "RATE" command

Tags: excel, math, excel-formula

I have less knowledge in Excel , now I want your help to calculate rate of interest in excel without using RATE command. (so that I can try to convert the formula in php)
This is the code we use in Excel

- B5= 60
- B4= 16070
- B3= 750000
- B6= 1

  =RATE(B5,B4,-B3,0,B6)*12

It should give a result of "10.75%" as rate.

How can I get the same result without using 'RATE' or any other commands?

Comment: This question is not related to the excel.

Comment: Ethun_Hunt@ it is related to Excel , I am not asking for help in php , I need help with a formula in Excel.

Comment: What he means is this is a mathematics question as you do not want to use inherent excel functions so it can be done on a calculator as easy as excel.

Comment: It can be done, but I guess it is not that easy because RATE is calculated by an iterative process. There is an excellent answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18840190/calculating-interest-rate-in-php

Comment: It is a better fit here, http://math.stackexchange.com/

Comment: A quick search on google finds this: https://www.math.nmsu.edu/~pmorandi/math210gs99/InterestRateFormulas.html which gives the formula to use to find the interest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [pgc01's answer](http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/277634-rate-formula-excel.html):

```
Function MyRATE(nper As Integer, pmt As Double, pv As Double, Optional fv As Double = 0, _
                              Optional PaymentEnd As Integer = 0, Optional guess As Double = 0.1)
    Dim a As Double, b As Double, c As Double ' coefficients of the equation
    Dim R As Double, RTmp As Double, i As Integer

    ' Initialize coefficients and R
    R = 1 + guess
    a = (pmt * (1 - PaymentEnd) - pv) / (pv + pmt * PaymentEnd)
    b = (fv - pmt * PaymentEnd) / (pv + pmt * PaymentEnd)
    c = (-pmt * (1 - PaymentEnd) - fv) / (pv + pmt * PaymentEnd)

    ' Iterate
    For i = 1 To 20
        RTmp = R - (R ^ (nper + 1) + a * R ^ nper + b * R + c) / ((nper + 1) * R ^ nper + a * nper * R ^ (nper - 1) + b)
        If Abs(RTmp - R) < 0.0000001 Then Exit For
        R = RTmp
    Next i

    If i <= 20 Then
        MyRATE = RTmp - 1
    Else
        MyRATE = "N/A" ' Must try another guess
    End If
End Function
```

[image]

***Note:***

This is not my code.  I have not tested it over a full range of inputs.

**EDIT#1:**

This is a *User Defined Function*.  User Defined Functions (UDFs) are very easy to install and use:

1. ALT-F11  brings up the VBE window
2. ALT-I
   ALT-M opens a fresh module
3. paste the stuff in and close the VBE window

If you save the workbook, the UDF will be saved with it.
If you are using a version of Excel later then 2003, you must save
the file as **.xlsm** rather than **.xlsx**

To remove the UDF:

1. bring up the VBE window as above
2. clear the code out
3. close the VBE window

To use the UDF from Excel worksheet cell:

=myrate(B5,B4,-B3,0,B6)*12

To learn more about macros in general, see:

http://www.mvps.org/dmcritchie/excel/getstarted.htm

and

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee814735(v=office.14).aspx

and for specifics on UDFs, see:

http://www.cpearson.com/excel/WritingFunctionsInVBA.aspx

**Macros must be enabled for this to work!**

Comment: Gary's Student@ Where should I use it ?

Comment: @Shijil Do you need instructions for installing and using this code??

Comment: At the same site I've seen this (re: http://www.excelforum.com/excel-programming-vba-macros/641515-rate-function-with-visual-basic.html) Btw, really good source of practical solutions. Best regards,

Comment: @AlexBell  Thank you for your kind comments.

Comment: Gary's Student@  just what type of script is it or where to apply it..  I am not expert in coding ..... :-(

Comment: You are welcome @Gary'sStudent ! Likewise, thanks for sharing this excellent solution. Best regards,

Comment: @Shijil  See my **EDIT#1:**

Comment: Gary's Student@ Thanks  Gary's Student , I will try it.